# Not able to install pmap on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Tags: memory-management, package, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install `pmap` package on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS machine. But I am always getting this error:

```
sudo apt-get install pmap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pmap
```

I have also ran the same these commands to upgrade the packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But I get the same result every time.

Note: I am trying to use `pmap` to basically look for memory mapping of a process. Let me know if you know any other command which can give me the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`pmap` is included in the package `procps` on Debian- and Ubuntu-based systems.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is pmap is deprecated.
According to [this CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmap/index.html):

> Package ‘pmap’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
>
> Formerly available versions can be obtained from the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/pmap/).
>
> Archived on 2018-03-21 as check issues were not corrected despite reminder.

If you go to that archive page, you'll find tar files for pmap 0.3.2 and 0.6.0.